# Преобразование Bitmap в drawable

Tags: java, android

Как преобразовать Bitmap в drawable ?

Comment: бурите в сторону `BitmapDrawable`  и еще... Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться.

Answer (score 8):

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Внезапно...